i have added the @token_required attribute , but still the route says token required
In postman, I am sending the request with bearer token but it says token not available below is the code:
import datetime
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask,jsonify,session,render_template,request
import jwt

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECURITY_KEY']='16b6e8fb778e418789a0e9ab90e0da9c'
app.secret_key='16b6e8fb778e418789a0e9ab90e0da9c'

def token_required(func):
    @wraps (func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if not token:
         return jsonify({'Alert!': 'Token is missing!' })
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, app.secret_key)
            return payload
        except:
            return jsonify({'Alert!': 'Invalid Token!' })
    return decorated


@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else: 
        return 'logged in currently'

@app.route('/login',methods=['post'])
def login():
    if request.form['username'] and request.form['password'] == 'amadmin':
        session['logged_in']=True
        token=jwt.encode({
            'username': request.form['username'],
            'expiration': str(datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(seconds=120))},app.secret_key)
        return jsonify({'token':token})
    else: 
        return 'invalid credentials'
    
@token_required
@app.route('/user')
@token_required
def user():
    return render_template('user.html')
    
if(__name__=='__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)

I am calling the '/user' route as below. I have added the bearer token. Why still I am not able to get the template?


In your token_required, you get token from request.args.get('token'). It's incorrect when you use Authorization postman.
You can see the curl in postman, the token was passed to header of request that not in the param request.

You must change your function to get token from header.
def token_required(func):
    @wraps (func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.headers.get('Authorization', '').split(" ")[1]
        if not token:
         return jsonify({'Alert!': 'Token is missing!' })
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, app.secret_key)
            return payload
        except:
            return jsonify({'Alert!': 'Invalid Token!' })
    return decorated

